# Split a collection into multiple collections in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Is it possible to split one collection into many smaller collections in MongoDB. There is no criteria about how documents are distributed.

Consider the following example:

```
Source collection: "AllRecords", record count: 1.1 Million
Batch Size: 200K 

result: 
10 new Collections "AllRecords" 1 to 10 with 200K records in each
and "AllRecords11" with 100K records 
* after success remove the original collection
```

Is there anyway in Mongo (aggregate pipeline, or any other way) to do this? Or is the only way looping through the collection?

PS: My application is written in Javascript however I don't think this does matter!

Comment: May I ask _why_ you want to break down a collection into many others? What's the purpose? How will this solve a specific problem?

Comment: Also, you can have unique indexes per collection, not a unique index that covers many collections at once. so, preventing duplicates across many collections is very hard, if possible at all.

Comment: @JeremyThille I don't want to break down the collection for performance purpose but mainly for audit and trace purpose. My software will create output files from each one of the smaller collections, If they're broken into multiple collections I know each output file is linked to one collection rather than many output files linked to one collection,

Comment: @JeremyThille I removed the duplicate part, what I meant was that one document should only be in one of the smaller collections but I guess that's given!